# Issue getting JS to apply to all class elements

Tags: javascript, html

Easier to show the code first, then I'll explain what I've tried (I'm a rookie so it might look like a hot mess but it partially worked.. it changed the first class element but nothing else.
For some reason it stopped working today even if I reverted the changes haha but doesn't change
that the problem of it not fully functioning.

```html
<div class="postdate">2020-09-08 16:00</div>
<div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
```

They are child divs in `<div>` then `<article> <div> <div><body><html>` if it makes any difference.

```js
function timefrom() {
  t = new Date(document.querySelector('.postdate').innerText);
  let postDate = t.getTime();
  let d = new Date();
  let currDate = Date.parse(d);
  let diff = (currDate - postDate) / 1000;
  let mindiff = diff / 60;
  let hrdiff = diff / 60 / 60;
  let daydiff = diff / 60 / 60 / 24;
  let minago = parseInt(mindiff);
  let hrago = parseInt(hrdiff);
  let dayago = parseInt(daydiff);
  if (minago <= 59) {
    (document.querySelector(".posttimefrom").innerHTML = minago + " Minutes ago.");
  } else if (minago >= 60 && hrago <= 23) {
    (document.querySelector(".posttimefrom").innerHTML = hrago + " Hours ago.");
  } else if (dayago <= 1) {
    (document.querySelector(".posttimefrom").innerHTML = dayago + " Days ago.");
  }
};
timefrom();
```

The only reason I'm using `querySelector` there is because that is the only instance I've managed to make it work in the days I've been trying to get it to work.

I've tried changing it to `QueryselectorAll`, `getElementsByClassName` with and without an `for` loop.
bin playing back and forth with adding removing () , different selectors, innerText/innerHTML.
and I just can't get it to work.

Anyone know what I'm missing?
I'm mainly suprised that I managed to get it to work with `queryselector` and not with `queryselectorALL`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sv">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <title>
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <header>
                <nav>
                    <div class="smallnav">
                        <a href="#" class="about">about</a>
                        <a href="#" class="contact">contact</a>
                        <a href="#" class="links">useful links</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="klockan">
                        <li class="hours">00</li>
                        <li class="minutes">00</li>
                        <li class="seconds">00</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
           </header>

           <div class="wrap">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <article class="navpost">
                        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
                        <div class="navpostflex">
                            <div class="navpostdate">2020-09-08</div>
                            <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        <p  class="navposttext">
                        </p>

                    </article>    
                    <article class="navpost">
                        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
                        <div class="navpostflex">
                            <div class="navpost-date">2020-09-08</div>
                            <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        <p  class="navposttext">
                        </p>

                    </article>
                    <article class="navpost">
                        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
                        <div class="navpostflex">
                            <div class="navpostdate">2020-09-08</div>
                            <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        <p  class="navposttext">
                        </p>

                    </article>    
    

            
                </div>
                <div class="maincontent">
                    <section class="Mainbtns">
                        <div class="btnsflex">
                            <a href="#" class="scrip">Small stuff</a>
                            <a href="#" class="fulljs">Full JS programs</a>
                            <a href="#" class="back">Backend Stuff</a>
                        </div>
                        
                        <h1></h1>



                    </section>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-17 13:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>    
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-16 14:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-15 16:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>



                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-11 12:30</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-10 11:30</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost" id="åttoende09">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-08 16:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-07 20:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-04 19:30</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-09-03 16:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-08-31 22:30</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                                <p class="maintext"></p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-08-24 20:30</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"> </p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-08-23 18:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"> </p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-08-18 17:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="maintext"> </p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="mainpost">
                        <div class="postflex">
                            <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
                            <div class="postdate">2020-08-17 17:00</div>
                            <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
                            <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <p> </p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

*2nd update. added all HTML.*
is the entire HTML with removed unneeded content inside

etc hope i didnt remove any > or something to break it , everything should work.
so there is the full html and JS code as per request. and some comments say "u used `querySelector` it only uses the first element"
read the explaination and ull know why :) i tried just changing `queryselector` to `queryselectorALL` and `getelementsbyclassname` but it wont work.

*3rd update, more tests*
As far as iv managed to see with this and `console.log`
is that as soon as i change `.querySelector` to `querySelectorAll`
for the `.postdate` it shows "invalid date" in the console.
when it comes to changing the `.posttimefrom` if i dont change `.postdate` it will recognize that its "2 days ago" but it wont change the HTML so its visable on the webpage like it did with `querySelector`.
Bin trying `For Loops` more or less with every part and entire function to try and make it itterate thru the classes and change em(yes without `querySelector` but nothing sticks.. no matter what i do as soon as `querySelector` is changed from `.postdate` the date it produces turns invalid.
any ideas?

Comment: Not Sure what your saying but in short you don't want to use query selector and make it so every single `posttimefrom` is changed right??

Comment: querySelector returns only the first matched element. Post your code with querySelectorAll/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Post your HTML with working [mre], you can use snippet in editor by pressing button `<>` You are talking about selecting HTML elements we don't see...

Comment: The reason "it changed the first class element but nothing else" is because `querySelector` returns only the first element it finds. You need to provide more info.

Comment: Alpha wolf gamer, correct.
as for Ajay,16nk its there is probably 100 diffrent alternative code attempts iv made to try and make it work. this is the closesest iv made it work hence why i posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution to the problem you posted, I changed `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` so that we can pick all the html elements which have a particular class name in it.

In your case you are picking elements having `className` `postdate`. using `queryselectorAll` gives you a `HTMLCollection` object which you can iterate just like arrays using `forEach` method like i did.

Then i checked the timestamp and used your logic to calculate the time difference of date from now.

Then since you HTML has div with classname `.posttimefrom` which is second sibling to the post date so i used `nextElementSibling` two times to reach to the posttimefrom div but you can use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementById`. I also made the timefrom function generic so that it will work with other section of html provided that html part has similar structure like `postdate`. I hope this explanation does not overwhelm you but i tried to explain as much as i could.

```js
function timefrom(className) {
  let timeCollection = document.querySelectorAll(className);
  timeCollection.forEach(function(item) {
    let postDate = new Date(item.innerText).getTime();
    let d = new Date();
    let currDate = Date.parse(d);
    let diff = (currDate - postDate) / 1000;
    let mindiff = diff / 60;
    let hrdiff = diff / 60 / 60;
    let daydiff = diff / 60 / 60 / 24;
    let minago = parseInt(mindiff);
    let hrago = parseInt(hrdiff);
    let dayago = parseInt(daydiff);
    if (minago <= 59) {
      item.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerText = minago + " Minutes ago.";
    } else if (minago >= 60 && hrago <= 23) {
      item.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerText = hrago + " Hours ago.";
    } else if (dayago >= 1) {
      item.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerText = dayago + " Days ago.";
    }
  })
};

timefrom('.navpostdate');
timefrom('.postdate');
timefrom('.navpost-date');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="smallnav">
        <a href="#" class="about">about</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact">contact</a>
        <a href="#" class="links">useful links</a>
      </div>
      <ul id="klockan">
        <li class="hours">00</li>
        <li class="minutes">00</li>
        <li class="seconds">00</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <article class="navpost">
        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
        <div class="navpostflex">
          <div class="navpostdate">2020-09-08</div>
          <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>
        <p class="navposttext">
        </p>

      </article>
      <article class="navpost">
        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
        <div class="navpostflex">
          <div class="navpost-date">2020-09-08</div>
          <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>
        <p class="navposttext">
        </p>

      </article>
      <article class="navpost">
        <h3 class="navpostheader">Header-text</h3>
        <div class="navpostflex">
          <div class="navpostdate">2020-09-08</div>
          <div class="navpostline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="navposttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>
        <p class="navposttext">
        </p>

      </article>



    </div>
    <div class="maincontent">
      <section class="Mainbtns">
        <div class="btnsflex">
          <a href="#" class="scrip">Small stuff</a>
          <a href="#" class="fulljs">Full JS programs</a>
          <a href="#" class="back">Backend Stuff</a>
        </div>

        <h1></h1>



      </section>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-17 13:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-16 14:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-15 16:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>



      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-11 12:30</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-10 11:30</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost" id="åttoende09">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-08 16:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-07 20:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-04 19:30</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-09-03 16:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-08-31 22:30</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>
        <p class="maintext"></p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-08-24 20:30</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"> </p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-08-23 18:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"> </p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-08-18 17:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p class="maintext"> </p>
      </article>
      <article class="mainpost">
        <div class="postflex">
          <h2 class="postheader"></h2>
          <div class="postdate">2020-08-17 17:00</div>
          <div class="postline">&mdash;</div>
          <div class="posttimefrom">1 hour ago</div>
        </div>

        <p> </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that is exacly what im looking for! thx! now im gonna sit down and go thru the changes you did so i can learn from them and understand the new changes you introduced me to :D